# Change comas on column show with percentajes tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I had one column with the values formated the following way: 12,48. To be able Tableau to interpret it as %, I have changed de number format by Right Click on **Measures>Default Properties>Number Format>Percentage with 2 decimal places.** But now my data is record on the column like this: 1248,00% and I need it to be 12,48%

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you choice 'Percentage with 2 decimal places' it your value (12,48) *100

the right where to do it is:
Measures>Default Properties>Number Format> numer personalisation> add ' %' on sifix